# Values not appending properly in a dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to graph some random numbers over time using matplotlib and cannot seem to get it to work.  the axis of the graph moves like I think it should, but no graph line appears.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from random import *

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def yaxis():
    yvalue = randint(1,10)
    return yvalue

def animate(i):
    ys = []
    xs = []
    yvalue = yaxis()
    global xvalue
    xvalue += 1
    ys.append(yvalue)
    xs.append(xvalue)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

xvalue = 0
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

What am I missing?  If I print out the ys or xs dictionary, they just show one value

Comment: `ys` and `xs` are *lists*. But anyway, every time you run `animate` you reset `ys` and `xs` to *empty lists*, i.e. `ys = []` and `xs = []`. Thus, they will only ever have a single element in them...

Comment: I just figured it out.  had to put the xs = [] an ys = [] outside of the function

Answer (score 1):

You should not reinitialize your **xs** and **ys** lists inside animate. For the moment the lists each only contain one value.
Something like this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from random import *

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def yaxis():
    yvalue = randint(1,10)
    return yvalue

def animate(i):
    global xvalue, xs, ys
    yvalue = yaxis()
    xvalue += 1
    print(xvalue, yvalue)
    # append to the full lists
    ys.append(yvalue)
    xs.append(xvalue)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

xvalue = 0
# Initialize outside the function
ys = []
xs = []
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=30)
plt.show()
```

Hope this help in your endeavor.